# .htaccess port rewrite for subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect all SUBDOMAINS, except portal.example.com from any port (usually it's 80 or 443) to port 30000.

e.g.

- example.com: (any port) shall have no change
- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com): (any port) shall have no change
- portal.example.com (any port) shall have no change
- a.example.com (any port) shall be updated to a.example.com:30000
- b.example.com (any port) shall be updated to b.example.com:30000
- *.example.com (any port) shall be updated to *.example.com:30000
- etc.

I currently have following `.htaccess`, directing example.com and *.example.com without change:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit refactored rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=30000
RewriteCond !^((?:www|portal)\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:30000%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written as per your shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond !^portal\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond (.*example\.com) [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^30000$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:30000%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```